# How can i iterate through each statement in the table and execute them one at a time

Tags: sql, lua

I've created a LUA script that creates a variable 'roles' which runs an SQL query to get a table containing a bunch of SQL statements. I have a for loop that iterates through each statement and execute them each time however im getting the error that my 'roles' variable is set as boolean. I've tried to manually set this variable to 'table' but that didnt fix my issue.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LUA SCRIPT "GRANT_RT_MIBI_SUPPORT_ROLE_TO_SCHEMA" () RETURNS ROWCOUNT AS

--Create variable ROLES which stores all of the roles that will be assigned to a schema when ran.
roles = pquery([[SELECT
    'GRANT CREATE SESSION TO RT_MIBI_SUPPORT;'  AS ROLES_TO_GRANT
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'GRANT SELECT ON ' || OBJECT_NAME || ' TO RT_MIBI_SUPPORT;'  AS ROLES_TO_GRANT
FROM
    SYS.EXA_DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE
    OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'RT_MIBI%' AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'SCHEMA';]])

--Iterate through each of the roles until all roles have been executed.
for i = 1, #roles, 1 do
    print(roles)
    i = i + 1
print(roles)
end
/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: When iterating the roles table, you should print out roles[i] to see what's the content of a roles element. Besides that, there's nothing wrong about your loop. If roles is a boolean before the loop, the problem is in the result returned by pquery.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that your SQL statement is not getting correctly executed and you're getting a boolean value false as result. What I would do is to check that the SQL statements are correct, execute them directly in an SQL console first. Then once you know the SQL statements are working, I would separate the GRANT and SELECT statements in two different queries. You're interested only in the result returned by SELECT I think.

Comment: @DiegoPino The SQL statements work when i checked them against the database and i got what im looking for. The select statement returns some GRANT statements which i want to iterate through one by one and execute. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Print out "type(roles)" after your pquery call to double-check it actually returns a table. If it prints out "boolean" your pquery call is not returning a table thus you cannot iterate it (the problem is not in the loop).

Comment: @DiegoPino Problem solved, thanks for the help!